# $result Always return 1 , instead of wanted ID from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

My problem is, how to make my code, return ID that is assigned to person i have in database, instead of 1-which i dont know from it comes.

```
Opiekun Prawny:<select id="text_box_od" name="fullname_opiekun" >
<?php   
while($rows = $resultimie->fetch_assoc())
{
$full_name_opiekun = $rows['full_name_opiekun'];    
echo "<option value='$full_name_opiekun'>$full_name_opiekun</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','aplikacja_kolonijna');
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Data base not found';
    }


    $fullname_opiekun = $_POST['fullname_opiekun'];

    $check = "SELECT id_opiekun FROM opiekun where concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun,' - ',pesel_opiekun) like '$fullname_opiekun'";
    $query =  mysqli_query($con,$check);

    $result = intval(mysqli_fetch_row($query));


    echo $result;
    echo $fullname_opiekun;
```

Actually person i'm calling is " Kazimierz Kowalczyk 14212312312"
and it's person  i have in my database , but with ID 3.

My  code, instead of return 3, when i check `echo $result;`  , return 1, all the time, and i have now idea, how to make  it work like i want.

When i'm checking `echo $full_name_opiekun;` it  shows me that my `SELECT` works and returns to me " Kazimierz Kowalczyk 14212312312"... why i can't  get right ID?

Comment: Just deleted intval, so it tells me that it can't be converted to string

Comment: @Dharman  can you please show me what exactly? Im totally newbie into PHP and stuff

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't complicate, this is enough:

```
//...
$check = "SELECT id_opiekun FROM opiekun where concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun,' - ',pesel_opiekun) like '$fullname_opiekun'";
$query =  mysqli_query($con,$check);

$result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
echo $result[0];  // as `fetch_row` returns 0-indexed array

// example to fetch associative array:
//$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
//echo $result['id_opiekun'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that when you have some input to pass into SQL you must use prepared statements and bind the parameters. If you use prepared statements then to fetch a single value from the result you only need to use `$stmt->bind_result($yourVariable)` and then `$stmt->fetch()`

I have fixed your code and also switched error reporting on. You should always make sure it is on.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aplikacja_kolonijna');
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$fullname_opiekun = $_POST['fullname_opiekun'];

// Execute the query
$check = "SELECT id_opiekun FROM opiekun where concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun,' - ',pesel_opiekun) like ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($check);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $fullname_opiekun);
$stmt->execute();

// Bind the first column as a result
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch(); // Fetch the value

echo $result;
echo $fullname_opiekun;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast the result array to an integer. You need to use the index.

You also should use prepared statements with parameterized queries, and use the error reporting function so you know when errors are returned.

```
$fullname_opiekun = $_POST['fullname_opiekun'];
$check = "SELECT id_opiekun FROM opiekun where concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun,' - ',pesel_opiekun) like ?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $check)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $fullname_opiekun);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id_opiekun);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    echo $id_opiekun;
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
    printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Warning : Mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result , bool given in line 25

Comment: i ve checked query in phpmyadmin, and it retruns  what i want,, if i replace `where concat (......) like '$fullname_opiekun' ` with `... like 'Kazimierz Kowalczyk 14212312312'`, then it shows me  his ID, ... maybe  you know what i did wrong in my query?

Comment: Now , when i pasted it in my code, there is no error, also doesn't echo anything... looks like it works, but no

Comment: Please try with the `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` moved.